# Which graph visualization library is suitable for static node and edges with text?

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

I would like to implement a graph in Java. I defined class `Node` and class `Edge`, and the graph is represented with a list of Node, and for each node, a list of edges starting from the node is defined as a field of the node. Now I would like to use some Java library to visualize the graph.

Currently I have tried [graphviz-java](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java). The result meets my requirement but the edges and nodes are not placed well. See the following graph below:

[image: graphviz-java result]

I created the graph with the API it provided like `node(xxx)`, `addLink()` through traversing the node list of my graph instead of generating the raw dot file text.

The key code of creating the graph is as follows:

```java
for (LiteralNode litNode : literalNodeArrayList) 
{     
    MutableNode mutableNode = mutNode(litNode.getNodeElement());     
    for (Edge e : litNode.getEdgeList()) {         
    MutableNode endNode = mutNode(e.endNode.getNodeElement());
    mutableNode.addLink(to(endNode.port(Compass.NORTH)).add(Arrow.VEE)); 
}     
    mutableNodes.add(mutableNode);     
    g.add(mutableNode); 
}
```

It's basically simple traverse with loops. The node and edges are dynamically changed according to different cases.

I would like the node and edges adjust the location to make the graph display better. I have also tried using json file and d3js to visualize the graph but I found those libraries focus too much on displaying huge amount of nodes and their distributions, which I don't need. I like the structure graphviz provided with some stratification. So I would like to get some recommendation.

I mentioned the json file because if no Java library is available, I might as well try some javascript library like d3js and only use java as a backend tool to generate json file I need to input. So the recommendation is not limited to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All graphviz attributes (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html) are supported.

- Node distances are set with "ranksep" and "nodesep".
- To force nodes on the same level, add a subgraph with "rank=same" and the nodes that should be aligned.

Here's a simple example:

```
Graph g = graph()
                .graphAttr().with(attr("ranksep", .1), attr("nodesep", .1))
                .with(graph().graphAttr().with(Rank.SAME).with(node("a"), node("c")))
                .with(node("a").link("b"), node("b").link("c"));
```

Comment: With these examples, I now understand how to use the attributes. Thanks for the answer and the work!

Answer (score 0):

The graph looks good to me. What do you mean by "I would like the node and edges adjust the location to make the graph display better."?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguity. Currently, the graph is too wide to display. I have set the `RankDir.BOTTOM_TO_TOP`, but I am not able to change the distance between nodes and edges. Another question is if it is possible to set some stratification of the graph such that some nodes are placed at a certain level. The documentation of this library I am referring to is only the readme part in the GitHub page, are there any more to refer to?